# Loop to split Large Data Frame and write multiple CSV files in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, dplyr

I have a file with 25 million rows and need to split it into smaller files based on the factor levels. I created a dataframe to include distinct factor levels and wrote a loop to perform some operations and write out a `csv`.

data looks like this:

```
Country Col2 Code   Year
 A       C     1    2020
 A       D     1    2020
 A       C     1    2020
 A       D     2    2020
 A       C     2    2020
 A       D     2    2020
 A       C     2    2020
 A       D     3    2020
```

Intention is to write a csv file for every subset based on code

```
d1 <- data %>%
  distinct(Code)
```

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d1))
{
  
  subset <- data %>%
  filter(Code  == Code[i])
  co <- subset$Code[i]
  
  yr<- subset$Year[i]
  

  setwd("C:/Users/...")
  
  write.csv(subset, paste(co,"_",Year, ".csv", sep=""), append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  
  }
```

The output keeps getting written to the same file instead of creating separate files in the directory.

IS there any better way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` to split data based on factor levels.

```
df_dat <- split(df, df$Code)
lapply(df_dat, function(x) write.csv(x, paste0('df_', x$col2[1], '.csv'), row.names = FALSE))
```

This will create separate dataframes in your working directory.

Comment: Thanks. So it effectively starts writing separate file, but the names is an issue. In my code, co represents a country name which will be stored in Col1 or Col2. This takes names of the columns

Comment: 1) How do you know then if name should be taken from `Col1` or `Col2` ?  2) Which `co` value do you want it to take? For example for `Code == 1` , `Col1` has A and B which should be written as file name?

Comment: Country name will always be stored in col2. Just checked

Comment: I am creating a subset in such a way that code == 1 will have just 1 country name. Will edit the sample data. Thanks

Comment: See updated answer.